# How to mock a function called by an object of a class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

I will start off by admitting that I have just got into python mock or any mock for that matter for a day or two.

So I have a python file that has a class in it:

MyFileA.py

```
class A:
    def Afunc():
        #do smthn
```

Now I want to mock a different script that uses this MyFileA.py

MyFileB.py

```
from MyFileA import A

def Bfunc():
    Aobj = A()
    ReturnVal = Aobj.Afunc()
```

How do I mock the statement `Aobj.Afunc()` to return a specific value?

Also, I am exclusively using decorators for mock method so I am expecting solutions in that format only.

Comment: "expecting"? How about "desiring"?

Comment: `@mock.patch('MyFileB.A.Afunc', return_value=42)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) to mock class `A` and `Afunc` and its returned value.

E.g.

`MyFileA.py`:

```py
class A:
    def Afunc():
        print('do smthn')
```

`MyFileB.py`:

```py
from MyFileA import A


def Bfunc():
    Aobj = A()
    ReturnVal = Aobj.Afunc()
    return ReturnVal
```

`test_MyFileB.py`:

```py
import unittest
from MyFileB import Bfunc
from unittest import mock


class TestMyFileB(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('MyFileB.A')
    def test_Bfunc(self, mock_A):
        a_instance = mock_A.return_value
        a_instance.Afunc.return_value = "mocked value"
        actual = Bfunc()
        self.assertEqual(actual, 'mocked value')
        mock_A.assert_called_once()
        a_instance.Afunc.assert_called_once()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
Name                                         Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/63429593/MyFileA.py            3      1    67%   3
src/stackoverflow/63429593/MyFileB.py            5      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/63429593/test_MyFileB.py      13      0   100%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                           21      1    95%
```